# SKCameraNode positioning on Mac: non-retina vs retina

Tags: macos, retina-display

I have a game that I’m porting from iOS to MacOS. On iOS, everything functions as it should on retina and non-retina devices. On Mac, it’s a different story.

I have two class properties: upperCameraPos and lowerCameraPos

The game is in a window and the scene is twice the height of this window’s content view (SKView). When the game starts. the camera node is positioned at lowerCameraPos, revealing the bottom half of the scene. When a button is pressed, SKAction’s moveToPoint: method is used to scroll the scene up, revealing the top half. On retina and 4K Macs, this works as expected.

However, on non-retina Macs (tested on late ’07 iMac & late ’08 MacBook), the same code for setting the camera’s initial position does not reveal the lower half of the scene, but rather shows the middle of the scene (which is the camera's default position).

I’ve done a considerable amount of searching and haven’t found any explanation for this. Does anyone know if there are any issues between retina & non-retina when positioning a camera node in a scene on Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I had the scene's scale mode set to SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill. After changing the scale mode to SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill, the camera node now scales to the correct parts of the scene regardless of whether the screen is retina or non-retina.